# How to pass dynamic value in schedule.rb file ( Ruby on rails )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

how I can pass dynamic value in regular expression

```
new_date_value = query_value
# minute(0-59), hours(0-23), day of month(1-31), month of year(1-12), day of week(0-6) 0=sunday

every '0 4 #{new_date_value} * *' do
   rake "db:get_free_tag_latest_post_batch", :environment => "production"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to avoid this kind of thing, what I usually do is check the date on the task. For example, I have a task that has to run every last day of the month. I can't use `30` or `31` on the day because Feb. has 28 days, for example.

This is how I set-up the task

```
# Apply interest accrued for all loans
# every day at: '22:00'
trigger_interest_accrued_application:
  cron: "0 22 * * *"
  class: "Jobs::TriggerInterestAccruedApplication"
  queue: admin
```

and on the task definition

```
class TriggerInterestAccruedApplication < ::ApplicationJob
  queue_as :admin

  def perform
    return unless Date.current.end_of_month.today?
    
    perform_task
  end
end
```

do you think something like this would work for you? IMO it is better because now what you want to do is put some logic on the scheduler file and this could probably bite you later

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will try